# How can I merge these two PHP snippets together to both send an email and send XML to a database?

Tags: php, xml, email

I am generating leads via website forms. The old system is to get the leads emailed using the below code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "Email Subject";

// data the visitor provided
$title = filter_var($_POST['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$first_name = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$last_name = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$when_to_call = filter_var($_POST['whentocall'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$house_number = filter_var($_POST['housenumber'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$postcode = filter_var($_POST['postcode'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$kw = filter_var($_POST['kw'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pos = filter_var($_POST['pos'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$device = filter_var($_POST['device'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$adgroup = filter_var($_POST['adgroup'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//constructing the message
$body = " From: $title $first_name $last_name\n\n Email: $email\n\n Phone: $phone\n\n When to call: $when_to_call\n\n House Name/Number: $house_number\n\n Postcode: $postcode \n\n Keyword: $kw \n\n Position: $pos \n\n Device: $device \n\n ad group: $adgroup";

// ...and away we go!
mail($to, $subject, $body);

// redirect to confirmation
header('Location: callbackconfirm.php');
} else {

}
?>
```

Our new system is to send the leads via XML straight into an online CRM, here is the code I have which works just fine:

```
<?php
echo "Thank you for your submission ".$_POST["firstname"]; 

$XML = "";
$XML .= "<Application><Cases><Case>";

$XML .= "<CreateCase>1</CreateCase>";

$XML .= "<FirstName>".$_POST["firstname"]."</FirstName>";

$XML .= "<LastName>".$_POST["surname"]."</LastName>";

$XML .= "<HomeTelephone>".$_POST["phone"]."</HomeTelephone>";

$XML .= "<HouseNumber>".$_POST["housenumber"]."</HouseNumber>";

$XML .= "<PostCode>".$_POST["postcode"]."</PostCode>";

$XML .= "<KEYWORD>".$_POST["kw"]."</KEYWORD>";

$XML .= "<ADGROUP>".$_POST["adgroup"]."</ADGROUP>";

$XML .= "<DEVICE>".$_POST["device"]."</DEVICE>";

$XML .= "<POSITION>".$_POST["pos"]."</POSITION>";

$XML .= "<URL>".$_POST["currentUrl"]."</URL>";

$XML .= "<IPADDRESS>".$_POST["ipaddress"]."</IPADDRESS>";

$XML .= "<SourceName>".$_POST["adgroup"]."</SourceName>";

$XML .= "</Case></Cases></Application>";

postXML($XML);



function postXML($XML){
$url = "CRM URL";

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
);

$post = http_build_query(
    array("XMLApplication" => $XML)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```

What I need is to be able to merge these two together so that when the magic submit button is pressed, it sends this XML feed into the software and generates the email at the same time.

I have tried and failed, can anybody help?

Many thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific about the problem you are having.

Comment: This seems too obvious, just copy the XML code inbetween the `mail()` and `header()` function calls. You will probably need to remove the `echo "Thanks...`

Comment: Right, so what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the code like this and remove the XML echo?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "Email Subject";

// data the visitor provided
$title = filter_var($_POST['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$first_name = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$last_name = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$when_to_call = filter_var($_POST['whentocall'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$house_number = filter_var($_POST['housenumber'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$postcode = filter_var($_POST['postcode'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$kw = filter_var($_POST['kw'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pos = filter_var($_POST['pos'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$device = filter_var($_POST['device'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$adgroup = filter_var($_POST['adgroup'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//constructing the message
$body = " From: $title $first_name $last_name\n\n Email: $email\n\n Phone: $phone\n\n When to call: $when_to_call\n\n House Name/Number: $house_number\n\n Postcode: $postcode \n\n Keyword: $kw \n\n Position: $pos \n\n Device: $device \n\n ad group: $adgroup";

// ...and away we go!
mail($to, $subject, $body);

$XML = "";

$XML .= "<Application><Cases><Case>";

$XML .= "<CreateCase>1</CreateCase>";

$XML .= "<FirstName>".$_POST["firstname"]."</FirstName>";

$XML .= "<LastName>".$_POST["surname"]."</LastName>";

$XML .= "<HomeTelephone>".$_POST["phone"]."</HomeTelephone>";

$XML .= "<HouseNumber>".$_POST["housenumber"]."</HouseNumber>";

$XML .= "<PostCode>".$_POST["postcode"]."</PostCode>";

$XML .= "<KEYWORD>".$_POST["kw"]."</KEYWORD>";

$XML .= "<ADGROUP>".$_POST["adgroup"]."</ADGROUP>";

$XML .= "<DEVICE>".$_POST["device"]."</DEVICE>";

$XML .= "<POSITION>".$_POST["pos"]."</POSITION>";

$XML .= "<URL>".$_POST["currentUrl"]."</URL>";

$XML .= "<IPADDRESS>".$_POST["ipaddress"]."</IPADDRESS>";

$XML .= "<SourceName>".$_POST["adgroup"]."</SourceName>";

$XML .= "</Case></Cases></Application>";   


function postXML($XML){
$url = "CRM URL";

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
);

$post = http_build_query(
    array("XMLApplication" => $XML)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

postXML($XML);

// redirect to confirmation
header('Location: callbackconfirm.php');
} else {

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, had to edit slightly because of problems my end, but this is what got me on the route to success!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?:

**PHP file**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "example@example.com";
    $subject = "Email Subject";

    // data the visitor provided
    $title          = filter_var($_POST['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $first_name     = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $last_name      = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email          = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $phone          = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $when_to_call   = filter_var($_POST['whentocall'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $house_number   = filter_var($_POST['housenumber'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $postcode       = filter_var($_POST['postcode'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $kw             = filter_var($_POST['kw'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pos            = filter_var($_POST['pos'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $device         = filter_var($_POST['device'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $adgroup        = filter_var($_POST['adgroup'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //constructing the message
    $body = " From: $title $first_name $last_name\n\n Email: $email\n\n Phone: $phone\n\n When to call: $when_to_call\n\n House Name/Number: $house_number\n\n Postcode: $postcode \n\n Keyword: $kw \n\n Position: $pos \n\n Device: $device \n\n ad group: $adgroup";

    // ...and away we go!
    mail($to, $subject, $body);

    //now the XML part...   
    echo "Thank you for your submission $first_name";

    $XML = "";
    $XML .= "<Application><Cases><Case>";
    $XML .= "<CreateCase>1</CreateCase>";
    $XML .= "<FirstName>$first_name</FirstName>";
    $XML .= "<LastName>$last_name</LastName>";
    $XML .= "<HomeTelephone>$phone</HomeTelephone>";
    $XML .= "<HouseNumber>$house_number</HouseNumber>";
    $XML .= "<PostCode>$postcode</PostCode>";
    $XML .= "<KEYWORD>$kw</KEYWORD>";
    $XML .= "<ADGROUP>$adgroup</ADGROUP>";
    $XML .= "<DEVICE>$device</DEVICE>";
    $XML .= "<POSITION>$pos</POSITION>";
    $XML .= "<URL>".$_POST["currentUrl"]."</URL>";
    $XML .= "<IPADDRESS>".$_POST["ipaddress"]."</IPADDRESS>";
    $XML .= "<SourceName>".$_POST["adgroup"]."</SourceName>";
    $XML .= "</Case></Cases></Application>";

    postXML($XML);

    // redirect to confirmation
    header('Location: callbackconfirm.php');

} else {

}


function postXML($XML){
    $url = "CRM URL";

    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    );

    $post = http_build_query(
        array("XMLApplication" => $XML)
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```

**EDIT:** Put the redirect after the XML part

Comment: Might be better to put the xml code before the `header('Location: callbackconfirm.php');'

Comment: Yeah I corrected this. Also there is a discrepancy - OP has `$_POST['surname']` and `$_POST['last_name']`, and in the XML part, `$_POST['adgroup']` is referenced twice.

Comment: Yea well basically OP is asking the obvious as they are not a programmer and want one of us to do all the work for them, for free of course. Depends how generous you are feeling as to whether you fix all the slightly non obvious issues for them as well

Comment: Meh, I'll leave the comments to alert them to the issues but I'm waiting for them to test the code before I invoice for work done...

Comment: LOL. Good luck with that.

Comment: Ha! Cheers for all the help, you're right, the variables were all over the place.

Comment: @benPearlKahan signed up to ask this question and need 15 points to upvote :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. You were right, the variables were all over the place.

This is what ended up working for me in the end:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "";
$subject = "Email Subject";

// data the visitor provided
$first_name     = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$surname        = filter_var($_POST['surname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phone          = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$housenumber    = filter_var($_POST['housenumber'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$postcode       = filter_var($_POST['postcode'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$kw             = filter_var($_POST['kw'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pos            = filter_var($_POST['pos'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$device         = filter_var($_POST['device'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$adgroup        = filter_var($_POST['adgroup'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$currentUrl     = filter_var($_POST['currentUrl'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ipaddress      = filter_var($_POST['ipaddress'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//constructing the message
$body = " From: $first_name $surname\n\n Phone: $phone\n\n  House Name/Number: $housenumber\n\n Postcode: $postcode \n\n Keyword: $kw \n\n Position: $pos \n\n Device: $device \n\n ad group: $adgroup \n\n URL: $currentUrl \n\n IP Address: $ipaddress";

// ...and away we go!
mail($to, $subject, $body);

//now the XML part...   


$XML = "";
$XML .= "<Application><Cases><Case>";
$XML .= "<CreateCase>1</CreateCase>";
$XML .= "<FirstName>$first_name</FirstName>";
$XML .= "<LastName>$surname</LastName>";
$XML .= "<HomeTelephone>$phone</HomeTelephone>";
$XML .= "<HouseNumber>$housenumber</HouseNumber>";
$XML .= "<PostCode>$postcode</PostCode>";
$XML .= "<KEYWORD>$kw</KEYWORD>";
$XML .= "<ADGROUP>$adgroup</ADGROUP>";
$XML .= "<DEVICE>$device</DEVICE>";
$XML .= "<POSITION>$pos</POSITION>";
$XML .= "<URL>".$_POST["currentUrl"]."</URL>";
$XML .= "<IPADDRESS>".$_POST["ipaddress"]."</IPADDRESS>";
$XML .= "<SourceName>".$_POST["adgroup"]."</SourceName>";
$XML .= "</Case></Cases></Application>";

postXML($XML);

// redirect to confirmation
header('Location: callbackconfirm.php');

} else {

}


function postXML($XML){
$url = "";

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
);

$post = http_build_query(
    array("XMLApplication" => $XML)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```